Is there a name for this vector bundle over the Grassmannian?
Let $ Gr(k,\mathbb{C}^n) $ be the Grassmannian of $ k $ dimensional subspaces of $ \mathbb{C}^n $. Let $ \mathscr{L} $ be some subspace of $ n \times n $ complex matrices. Over each point $ W \in Gr(k,\mathbb{C}^n) $ assign the space of sesquilinear forms $ \ell_T^W: W \times W \to \mathbb{C} $ for all $ T \in \mathscr{L} $. Here
$$
 \ell_T^W: (w_1, w_2) \mapsto w_1^\dagger T w_2
$$
where $ \dagger $ is the conjugate transpose. So the bundle has the vector space $ \{ \ell_T^W: T \in \mathscr{L} \} $ over each point $ W $ in the Grassmannian $ Gr(k,\mathbb{C}^n) $.
I've been thinking about/ trying to learn more about Grassmannians and vector bundles. Is there a name for this vector bundle over the Grassmannian? (Is it even smooth?) Does it have constant rank? When $ \mathscr{L} $ is the space of all linear operators on $ V $ then I think the bundle has constant rank $ k^2 $, otherwise I'm not sure. (and, as Michael Albanese points out, when $ \mathscr{L} $ is just the scalar multiples of the identity then the bundle has constant rank $ 1 $)
1st version, I tried to be too abstract and lost the flavor of the original idea that inspired me, it ended up being trivial as pointed out in the comments by Michael Albanese:
Let $ Gr(k,V) $ be the Grassmannian of $ k $ dimensional subspaces of $ V $. Let $ \mathscr{L} $ be some subspace of linear operators on $ V $. Over each
point $ W \in Gr(k,V) $ assign the space of linear maps $ \ell_T^W: W^* \otimes W \to \mathbb{C} $ for all $ T \in \mathscr{L} $. Here
$$
 \ell_T^W: w_1^* \otimes w_2 \mapsto w_1^*(T(w_2)) 
$$
So the bundle has the vector space $ \{ \ell_T^W: T \in \mathscr{L} \} $ over each point $ W $ in the Grassmannian $ Gr(k,V) $.

$\ell_T^W$ is only defined if $T(W) \subseteq W$. If you require $T(W) \subseteq W$ for all subspaces $W$, then $T$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{id}_V$.

@MichaelAlbanese Ah ok I think something got lost in translation when I tried to make it too abstract, let me just give what I was originally thinking of in terms of matrices

Now it seems you have the bundle $(\bar E\otimes E)^*$, where $E$ is the tautological bundle on $G(k,V)$ whose fiber over $W$ is $W$. (Topologists call this the universal bundle, but complex geometers tend to use the more precise terminology, as there are at least two obvious universal bundles on the Grassmannian.)

@TedShifrin Ah I see so if we take $ \mathscr{L} $ to be the space of all $ n \times n $ matrices then we get $ (E \otimes E)^* $ where $ E $ is the tautological bundle on $ Gr(k,\mathbb{C}^n) $ whose fiber over $ W $ is $ W $. And if we take $ \mathscr{L} $ to be all multiples of the identity matrix then we get a trivial rank 1 bundle over $ Gr(k,\mathbb{C}^n) $. What if $ \mathscr{L} $ is some other subspace of matrices? Will we even get a constant rank bundle?

I don’t follow this, no. The linear maps on $W$ are given by $E^*\otimes E$ (which is a holomorphic vector bundle). All $n\times  n$ matrices is a trivial vector bundle of rank $n^2$.
